# ValueError: Negative seek position

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh

В моем коде:

```
account = Account(user_name, user_password)
ssh = SSH2()
ssh.connect(ipAddress)
```

начиная с следующей строчки возникает ошибка:

> ValueError: Negative seek position -150

```
ssh.login(account)
ssh.execute('conf t')
ssh.send('exit\r')
.....
ssh.execute('exit')
ssh.send('exit\r')
```

надо зайти на оборудование и выполнить несколько команд. Что это может быть, с чем связано?

Comment: Укажите, пожалуйста, какую именно библиотеку Вы используете(ссылка на pypi или git)?